# the Hyperbolic space has constant sectional curvature $-1$, why is not contradict to the Hadamard Theorem?

Tags: differential-geometry

the Hadamard Theorem says that any simply connected, complete Riemannian manifold of non-positive sectional curvature is diffeomorphic to $R_{n}$. I know this is a stupid question, but what am I missing here?

Comment: Hyperbolic space is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: So that's how it is..I am learning differential geometry by myself, the textbook never mention that. Thanks.